# gparted does not recognise windows 10 partition

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, windows-10, partitioning

I have a lenovo yoga 900 with windows 10 pre-installed in a 250GB SSD hard drive. I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows. I am using a bootable USB stick and have selected the option "Try Ubuntu" in order to create a new partition for my Ubuntu installation. However, gparted only recognizes two  partitions of size 4.1MB and 14.9GB as shown in the picture

[image: here]

The problem is that I cannot see the 250GB space.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sda` is your installation media. Your hard drive is something else, probably `/dev/sdb`

Comment: This is correct.  Notice the file system type is FAT32.

Comment: I have edited the question.